# How to Install software after deploying my stack in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to install software or create files or update files to the instance after i created the stack.
`AWS::CloudFormation::Init` if we use this we need to run the Userdata script and this will restart the server (or terminate the first instance and create a new instance ) but i don't want to create or delete the first instance.

Is their any way to directly install the software form CloudFormation.

please help

Comment: What is it that you think restarts (or terminates) the instance? A typical userdata script does not do this.

Comment: I think OP already has an AWS::CloudFormation::Init section in an ASG and as such new userdata would trigger the creation of a new instance. @OP: You cannot provision software in CloudFormation in a way that would not trigger the creation of a new instance.

Your options are: create it in UserData, create it as Chef recipies (and trigger chef on a change in the metadata), or use a new AMI. The second option ALSO requires a new instance to be created but subsequent deploys can be triggered by modification of the metadata, in which case cfn-init will orchestrate running the cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Ceph instance being created.  the userdata script is used to install software and you will see an example of it creating the file /etc/logrotate.d/allvarlogs.  It is just a bash script coded up in the cloudformation.

```
 "CephServerInstance1" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "DependsOn" : "StaticIPAddress1",
  "Properties": {
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
      {
         "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
         "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : { "Ref": "EbsDeviceSize" } }
      },
      {
         "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda2",
         "Ebs" : {
           "VolumeSize" : { "Ref": "DataDeviceSize" },
           "DeleteOnTermination" : true,
           "Encrypted" : false
         }
      }
    ],
    "IamInstanceProfile" : { "Ref" : "InstanceProfile"},
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key" : "Name",
        "Value" : "ceph-1"
      }
    ],
    "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "ImageId" },
    "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
    "KeyName"  : { "Ref": "KeyName" },
    "SourceDestCheck": false,
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
      {
        "NetworkInterfaceId": { "Ref": "StaticIPAddress1" },
        "DeviceIndex": 0
      }
    ],
    "CreditSpecification": {
      "CPUCredits": "standard"
    },
    "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash\n",
      "yum -y update\n",
      "yum -y install epel-release\n",
      "yum install -y htop\n",
      "yum install -y vim\n",
      "curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py\n",
      "python get-pip.py --user\n",
      "export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH\n",
      "pip install awscli --upgrade --user\n",
      "yum erase -y 'ntp*'\n",
      "yum -y install chrony\n",
      "echo 'server 169.254.169.123 prefer iburst' >> /etc/chrony.conf\n",
      "systemctl restart chronyd\n",
      "# Set up log rotation\n",
      "cat <<EOF >/etc/logrotate.d/allvarlogs\n",
      "/var/log/*.log {\n",
          "rotate ${LOGROTATE_FILES_MAX_COUNT:-5}\n",
          "copytruncate\n",
          "missingok\n",
          "notifempty\n",
          "compress\n",
          "maxsize ${LOGROTATE_MAX_SIZE:-100M}\n",
          "daily\n",
          "dateext\n",
          "dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s\n",
          "create 0644 root root\n",
      "}\n",
      "EOF\n",
      "echo done > /home/centos/done.txt\n"
    ]]}}
  }
},
```

Comment: but this will restart the instance ? I dont want to restart the server .

Comment: Hi @Akshay, during the stack launch, the Userdata script will not restart the instance.  I am not sure what you need, are you talking about installing software after the cloudformation launch is complete?